# Cross-browser method to capture scroll events (or an easier way to temporarily disable scrolling)

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, dom-events

I'm trying to execute a Javascript function whenever a user scrolls a page.

I've tried:

```
<body onscroll="myScrollFunction()">
```

and this works fine in Firefox but not IE.

I also tried:

```
window.onscroll = "myScrollFunction()";
```

but this seems to only perform the function once, similar to an onload event, but further scrolls do not fire the event. My doctype is set to strict; not sure if this makes a difference or not.

How can I get this to work across all browsers?

What I'm trying to accomplish is a way to prevent users from scrolling once a modal is displayed. I'd rather not use

```
overflow:hidden
```

because the document shifts slightly when the modal is displayed (to compensate for the scrollbar), so I figured I could capture the scroll function and lock it to the top of the page whenever the modal is displayed. If there is an easier way to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
window.onscroll = myScrollFunction();
```

which assigns the result of the `myScrollFunction()` to the onscroll handler, you want

```
window.onscroll = myScrollFunction;
```

which assigns the function itself, and will therefore be called on each scroll.

Comment: Ha, you beat me in time. so I deleted mine and +1 on your.

Comment: This actually works, thanks. I still don't understand how removing the brackets made this work; would you mind explaining?

Comment: Also, in addition, IE seems to have a slight delay when firing the function. The function that I want called onscroll simply keeps the scroll position to the top of the page. In firefox whenever the user tries to scroll, it freezes completely, which is perfect. In IE however, whenever a user scrolls, the page 'jumps' slightly. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Sure; the function name in its own is just a reference to the function, like a variable. Placing brackets after the function name invokes that function, i.e. runs whatever code is inside the function. Your example is running the function right away, whereas the fix ensures that the function runs when the event is triggered.

Comment: Well, with the quotes around `"myScrollFunction()"`, you're just assigning a string to `window.onscroll` -- in other words, doing absolutely nothing, since you can't assign a string to an event.

Comment: Anyway, it sounds like the CSS-based solution provided by Pointy is more appropriate to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that instead of doing that, you just give your modal dialog `position: fixed;` which will fix it to the viewport instead of the page.

Comment: This causes the modal to stay on the screen but still allows the user the scroll the page in the background, which is something that I don't want happening.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent scrolling?  It's frustrating to a user to be unable to do something they're accustomed to doing, especially something as basic as scrolling a scrollable page.

Comment: @Pointy, user1279153 mentioned disabling page scrolling in the context of an open modal window, which is understandable. We're all familiar with the problems a scrollable viewport inside a scrollable viewport brings. For instance, the page may scroll instead of the modal window, which is not what the user intended. If the user wanted to continue scrolling down the page, they would close the modal window first.

Closing a window is also very basic.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `<body>`'s `overflow` to `hidden` while your lightbox is open.

```
$('body').css('overflow','hidden');
```

...then return to normal when it closes:

```
$('body').css('overflow','auto');
```

Comment: As stated above, While this works, the appearance (or disappearance) or the scrollbar causes the body to shift horizontally. I don't want this to happen

Comment: Content doesn't shift at all for me in Chrome.